# Migration from FTP to SFTP with the same user

Tags: rhel, ftp, sftp

We will start to use SFTP instead of FTP for Tibco BW 5 application on RHEL 6. The port 22 is already open. Can i keep the same user account and directory for SFTP? If so, should i change any directory/user permissions?

Comment: What research/efforts you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's bit too broad question. It depends on what FTP and SFTP server software you are using and how those servers manage the user accounts. But I'll try to answer anyway, to give you some clue, what to look for. If you give us more details, you might get better answers.

- You might use the same software for both FTP and SFTP. Then the FTP and SFTP will share the accounts. For example ProFTPD supports both FTP and SFTP.
- You might use a different software for FTP and SFTP. But they can still share the accounts, typically in case they both use operating system accounts. For example OpenSSH SFTP server use operating system accounts.
- But if your FTP and SFTP server software have their own account management, then you will have to set up new accounts for SFTP.

Comment: If you find yourself starting an answer with "your question sounds too broad", then please consider flagging or voting to close the question as too broad. Answerable questions are the target, so if the OP can narrow it down, please feel free to comment on the question with guidance to narrow it. Thank you!

Comment: Honestly, your answer enlarged my vision about the solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

SFTP and FTP are different protocols (despite the name similarity), hence no, I don't know of any way you can have the same account since there is no migration possible.